# Lineno and figures

Tags: floats, lineno

I am writing a document to submit to a journal and I am facing this weird problem : I am using the lineno package before submitting the paper and when I am loading it the last two figures of my document disappear! I have no idea where does this comes from and it's very difficult to reproduce it in a MWE.

The full code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/xeYm10Fr)

It is strange that this happens even if I just include the package i.e. `\usepackage{lineno}`, without include `\linenumbers`.

With `\include{lineno}`

[image]

Without `\usepackage{lineno}`

[image]

Any idea on what that might be happening?

A MWE is the following

```
\documentclass[epj, twocolumn]{webofc}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}   % Web of Conferences font

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\vfill\oldbibitem}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth,clip]{subthreshold.png}
    \caption{Comparison between present data (black points) and ENDF/B-VII.1 evaluation (red line) in the energy range $100\;keV-600\;keV$. Data is shown using a binning of 2000 bins per energy decade.}
    \label{subthreshold}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth,clip]{subthreshold.png}
    \caption{Comparison between present data (black points) and ENDF/B-VII.1 evaluation (red line) in the energy range $100\;keV-600\;keV$. Data is shown using a binning of 2000 bins per energy decade.}
    \label{subthreshold}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth,clip]{subthreshold.png}
    \caption{Comparison between present data (black points) and ENDF/B-VII.1 evaluation (red line) in the energy range $100\;keV-600\;keV$. Data is shown using a binning of 2000 bins per energy decade.}
    \label{subthreshold}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth,clip]{subthreshold.png}
    \caption{Comparison between present data (black points) and ENDF/B-VII.1 evaluation (red line) in the energy range $100\;keV-600\;keV$. Data is shown using a binning of 2000 bins per energy decade.}
    \label{subthreshold}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.99\columnwidth,clip]{subthreshold.png}
    \caption{Comparison between present data (black points) and ENDF/B-VII.1 evaluation (red line) in the energy range $100\;keV-600\;keV$. Data is shown using a binning of 2000 bins per energy decade.}
    \label{subthreshold}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The log output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Tr5BMAju)

From the 5 figures, when I include `lineno`, only the first 3 appear.

Note that I am running the code on shareLaTeX.

Comment: What does the console output or log file say? What does `\include{lineno}` do? This tells LaTeX to include the file `lineno.tex`. Is that intended? But really, we need an MWE here. Your question won't be helpful to other users if it depends on an external link whose content will change. Making an MWE is just a mechanical process. Remove stuff and put it back only if the problem disappears.

Comment: Don't use `h` as the sole specifier for floats. Usually, LaTeX will replace this by `ht` anyway, but trying to restrict it in this way is most unwise.

Comment: @cfr Done! Thanks for your comment! So what should I use instead of `[h]` ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen if there isn't room here? `h` says 'put it here, if there's room'.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with a standard class, change `webofc` to that class. Otherwise, the class is part of the issue and we'll need a link to it as it is not standard. Also, we can't reproduce without the image. Try using `example-image-a` and see if you can reproduce the problem with that.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat but it is better to use `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` package than to use `H` from `float`.

Comment: I changed the document class to `\documentclass[11pt, two column]{article}` and it seems that there is no problem there, so it should come from the class...

Comment: You need to provide a link to the class, in that case, as we cannot reproduce the issue without it and it is not part of standard TeX distributions.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last except for a few exceptions, such as `cleverref` which need `hyperref` loaded first. This isn't why your images disappear, probably, but may cause issues of other kinds.

Comment: The class can be found here ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/web-conf/

Comment: @cfr : You are right. Even if I change the order of the packages, nothing really happens.